# Create a footer using re-com box layout containers

Tags: flexbox, clojurescript

I want to have an h-box along the bottom of the page but what I have done so far does not work:

```
(defn simple-title [txt]
  [re-com/title
   :label txt
   :level :level1])

(defn main-panel []
  (fn []
    [v-box
     :height "100%"
     :children [[h-box
                 :width "100%"
                 :children [(simple-title "Should see right at top of page (works)")]
                 :align-self :start]
                [h-box
                 :width "100%"
                 :gap "3em"
                 :align-self :end
                 :children [(simple-title "Want right at bottom (not working)") (simple-title "Just to its right")]]]]))
```

My understanding is that `:align-self :end` should do the trick. However what happens is that the second `h-box` appears at the top of the page, directly below the first `h-box`.

Comment: If there's a way to demo the problem in flexbox natively please post. Sorry, I'm not familiar with ClojureScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested) and be sure to read the docs:  http://re-demo.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/#/layout

```
(defn main-panel []
  (fn []
    [v-box
     :height "100%"
     :width  "100%"               ;; <-- added 
     :children [[h-box
                 :size "auto"     ;; <-- will expand to fill available space
                 :children [(simple-title "Should see right at top of page (works)")]
                 :align-self :start]
                [h-box
                 :size "none"   ;; <--  natural size (height)
                 :gap "3em"
                 :align-self :end
                 :children [(simple-title "Want right at bottom (not working)") (simple-title "Just to its right")]]]]))
```

Comment: That makes `:align-self :end` *work* by putting what is inside the second h-box to the right of the page. Unfortunately however it is still at the top. So now my question is: "How to make it interpret :end as being the bottom?"

Comment: That  :align-self :end  works on the h-box itself,  not on it's two children.

So ":align-self :end"  pushes the hbox  itself across to the "end" (right) on the cross axis of its vbox parent.  Have you been through a good tutorial like:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Try removing ":align-self :end".  You may get what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have played with your code and come up with this:

```
(defn main-panel []
  (fn []
    [re-com/v-box
     :height "100%"
     :children [[re-com/h-box
                 ;:width "100%"  ;; <-- not needed because parent v-box :align defaults to :stretch
                 :children [(simple-title "Should see right at top of page (works)")]
                 ;:align-self :start  <-- not needed for same reason as :width "100%" above
                 ]
                [re-com/box  ;; <-- this is the magic that will push the h-box below to the bottom (actually, it's the :size "auto" that does it).
                 :size "auto"
                 :child ""]
                [re-com/h-box
                 ;:width "100%"  ;; <-- not needed for same reason as :width "100%" above
                 :gap "3em"
                 :align-self :end
                 :children [(simple-title "Want right at bottom (now working)")
                            (simple-title "Just to its right")]]]]))
```

I also added some comments about arguments you don't need and why.

Lastly, I notice you using () for the `simple-title` component. Please refer to:

https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Using-%5B%5D-instead-of-%28%29

to understand the subtle difference between using () and using [].